# Is it possible to embed Google Analytics eCommerce dashboard into swift application

Tags: swift, google-analytics, e-commerce

I'm building a swift app with the purpose of showing GA ecommerce sales from multiple vendors on my website. Each vendor can register on the app and then the access of their sales data will be granted to their user so they can follow their sales.
The ecommerce tracking is preformed by Google Analytics so is there any way where I can embed my eCommerce dashboards onto my swift app?

Comment: Maybe use a webview to display the dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can not.**

There's no such API available for that intent, the way you want it. You must use theirs...

I am very sorry to tell you, but its is the plain truth.

Welcome!

Comment: Do you have a suggestion how I could track my sales of different vendors on Squarespace? Or any smart way I can get my data from either GA og Squarespace?